# Get Background location During Splash Screen

Tags: codenameone

My app requires that I get the currentLocation of the user during the splash screen process. I have implemented it by calling a detectLocation() in the init(), actually its the first line of my init. It works but the challenge is it shows a black screen while the location is being detected.

How can I seamlessly perform this process without the black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that during the `init(Object)` or the `start()` calls. You should let them complete and only then fetch the location. e.g.:

```
mySpalsh.addShowListener(e -> backgroundLocation());
mySplash.show();
```

It's possible you would need to further defer this depending on the way in which you fetch background location using something like:

```
mySpalsh.addShowListener(e -> callSerially(() -> backgroundLocation()));
mySplash.show();
```